# sharepoint - deploy web service without creating a virtual directory

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, iis, service

I have a wcf web service and want to deploy that to my sharepoint solution.

in IIS I have created a virtual directory that points to the webservice in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80_wcf. the web service was copied across from the 12 hive to this directory.

is there a nicer way of just deploying the web service and not having to  do any of this stuff of copying across web services (.svc + web.config files)...and creating a virtual directory etc..

Answer (score 0):

This guide for [web services on sharepoint](http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/08/web-services-on-sharepoint-making-f5.html) should be a good start. You may want to make the solution into a wsp for deployment and use the activate/deactivate feature code to add/remove your wcf configuartion entries to the sharepoint web.config.